# Symfony2 Twig disable HTML Rendering

Tags: html, json, rest, symfony, twig

how to turn off the rendering of html responses in twig?

I'm building a RESTful API and want to completly disable HTML rendering. For example if I request /foo/bar without an oAuth Access Token, symfony2 should responses with a 401 json message instead of a 401 html template.

Greetings

Comment: Are you using the FOSRestBundle? IMHO if you are calling a page with the browser you're requesting a text/html. Have you already tried with curl and `Accept: application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't call the **render** method : `return $this->render('FooBarBundle:Default:index.html.twig');`

Instead of this, you can call in your controller :

```
return new JsonResponse(array(
    'message' => 'Your message here'
), 401);
```

Comment: I think the more appropriate way would be to actually return HTTP error code: `return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Your message here'), 401);`

Comment: Hey...thanks for your responses. Yes, I'm using fosRestBundle and I only call return array('foo' => $bar->getFoo()) in my controllers. So you would prefer, to extend the twig exception controller and return a JsonResponse? I think this is a good way to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know you're using FosRestBundle. You can find more informations here : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/4-exception-controller-support.md

Comment: Yeah I skipped that topic when I was researching bundles :)

Answer (score 0):

1- Use fosrestbundle.
2- In your config.yml file, put "defaults: {_format: json}" in configuration bundle.
3- In your controller, just throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('optional custom message').
It should do the job.

If you don't wanna use this bundle:
use _format: json in your routing.yml.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to add an exception listener, and return a JSON response:

```
class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $ex = $event->getThrowable();

        $response = new JsonResponse([
            'error' => [
                'message' => $ex->getMessage(),
            ],
        ]);

        /**
         * Set the status code based on your business logic.
         */
        if ($ex instanceof SomeParameterIsMissingException) {
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        // } elseif (/* map other exceptions you care about to status codes */) {
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

[How to create an exception listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)